# File encoding the same code Windows, Linux

Tags: python, linux, windows, python-3.x, text-files

Can someone tell me why the same code works fine on Linux but it is not on Windows?

The following code was executed on each os:

```
print("Output :" + open("data.txt", "r").read())
```

On Windows error was raised:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 1: character maps to <undefined>
```

But on Linux everything worked fine:

```
Output :☀♠☂
```

Where is the problem ?

Comment: `print(sys.getdefaultencoding())` would be interesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose your file is UTF-8, which is the default encoding on Linux but not on Windows. The default encoding is used if not specified.

Consider passing the encoding explicitly:

```
open("data.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
```

(Note that this is where Python 2 and Python 3 handle things differently. With Python 2, you'd get raw bytes, as if you specified `"rb"` under Python 3.)

Comment: Actually in Python 2 on Windows `"r"` mode translates `"\r\n"` to `"\n"`. You need `"rb"` mode to get raw bytes on Windows.

Comment: @eryksun: Yes, this is the "universal newline" thing, related but diffrerent.

Comment: It's not `"rU"` mode, i.e. reading in *universal* (as in cross-platform) newline mode. That's specific to Python. It's just regular text mode using Windows standard I/O `FILE` streams, i.e. `"r"` mode defaults to `"rt"` mode.